# One-way mirror with both sides lit

Tags: optics, reflection

is there already a technology that provides one-way viewing glass with no regard to whether the back side is lit or not?
the case is:
two rooms (A and B) side by side, people in room A want to see directly into room b without room b knowing, all the while room A must be lit all the time of viewing is there such a glazing solution for this problem?

Comment: how about this https://vasglass.gr/index.php/en/one-way-mirror

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as one way glass.
How "one way glass" works in reality is that one room is lit up and one room is dark.

Here's a picture from [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/#:%7E:text=What%20if%20you%20shined%20a,of%20one%2Dway%20mirror%20glass%3F&text=Believe%20it%20or%20not%2C%20you,reflects%20it%20the%20other%20way.) explaining it.
[image]

Comment: yea, been looking for some magic here. suppose in the end there can only be a camouflage thingy.... waiiiiiit.... does anyone remember that tent, in which people inside can see outside but from outside its just plain fabric?! does anyone know about it?! k back to google then, thanks.

Comment: ugh nevermind, turns out its the same principle, just cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exists as a standard item, but I think conceivably you could have the room A lit with polarized light, and the screen given a polarization at 90° to that, so that virtually all of the light from room A is blocked from entering room B.  Whereas room B would be lit with either unpolarized light, or light with polarization aligned to the screen so most of it passes.

Comment: that's worth trying, very interesting. like, with my limited knowledge, I was thinking of using a certain wavelength in room a, then putting a film that filters that wavelength. and standard silver in room B. Tho I still hope there is a way to make the silver non-reflective towards the A side also.... I'm going to lookup how polarized light works.